# Unable to get the correct data format in req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to parse the body to nodeJS but I get it back in the wrong format.

This is my code:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/email", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },

      body: JSON.stringify({ shareUrl: props.shareUrl })
    });`
```

This is how it is parsed when console.log(body.req.shareUrl) in Node

```
{ '{"shareUrl":"link"}': '' }
```

this is how I want it back

```
{ 'shareUrl': 'link' }
```

**EDIT**

When I try to send it from Postman it works fine

[image]

I get following output:

```
{ Name: 'jej' }
```

Comment: What if you remove `JSON.stringify` from `body` ?

Comment: I've already tried that, same problem :/

Comment: Can you try setting your header to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: I've already tried that too, same results

Comment: check if you've `stringified` your `props.shareUrl`

Comment: Can you be more specific, I'm not quiet sure what u want me to do

Comment: share what your `props.shareUrl` is

Comment: On what, you're performing console.log()?
- body.req.shareUrl
- body.req

Comment: It isnt really important what value is in props.shareUrl because I have the same problem even if i change it with a hardcoded string

Comment: @ArsalImam On both, body.req shows the above and body.req.shareUrl shows undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The Content type:

```
{ "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
```

is not ment to send the JSON data in the first place.

If you want to send and receive JSON, change the content type to:

```
{ "Content-Type": "application/json" }
```

like:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/email", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: { data: json.stringify({shareUrl: props.shareUrl}) }
    });`
```

On server you will find it under req.body.data

Comment: This whole thing have to be stringified `{ data: json.stringify({shareUrl: props.shareUrl}) }` check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch